# Reverse connectivity between servers with HAProxy

Tags: ssl, haproxy, proxypass

I'm trying to securely connect two servers (using reverse connectivity) using HAProxy. I'm using the following config for the proxy:

```
    global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    #log loghost    local0 info
    maxconn 4096
    uid 99
    gid 99
    daemon
    debug

defaults
    log     global
    log-format {"type":"haproxy","timestamp":%Ts,"http_status":%ST,"http_request":"%r","remote_addr":"%ci","bytes_read":%B,"upstream_addr":"%si","backend_name":"%b","retries":%rc,"bytes_uploaded":%U,"upstream_response_time":"%Tr","upstream_connect_time":"%Tc","session_duration":"%Tt","termination_state":"%ts"}
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    option http-server-close
    maxconn 250
    timeout connect  5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend front_reverse
    mode http
    bind haproxy:8081 ssl crt /x509/certs/example.com.pem
    use_backend back_reverse

backend back_reverse
    mode http
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server onpremsrv example.com:8882 check
    http-request set-header X-Real-IP %[src]
    option forwardfor

listen stats 
    bind haproxy:9000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats hide-version
    stats auth admin:admin
```

The server that receives the traffic from the backend outputs the following:

```
 onprem_1       | TRACE [ssl#8 172.32.0.4:39376] RECEIVED: RESPONSE: 503 Service Unavailable HTTP/1.0 HEADERS: {Cache-Control=[no-cache], Connection=[close], Content-Type=[text/html]} CONTENT: HeapBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=0: empty] [...]  [...]
 onprem_1       | TRACE [ssl#8 172.32.0.4:39376] RECEIVED: CONTENT: HeapBuffer[pos=105 lim=212 cap=272: 3C 68 74 6D 6C 3E 3C 62 6F 64 79 3E 3C 68 31 3E...] [...]
 onprem_1       | TRACE [tcp#7 172.32.0.4:39376] RECEIVED: SESSION_UNSECURED
```

The connection to the second server gets closed. I believe it's related to the ssl part of the HAProxy config. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect the two servers using SSL passthrough. The whole setup runs in docker containers. First of all, I changed the hostname I used when generating the certificates. (using the haproxy hostname) Then I slightly modified the *haproxy.cfg* to reflect the changes in the *docker-compose.yml*.

```
    global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    #log loghost    local0 info
    maxconn 4096
    uid 99
    gid 99
    daemon
    debug

defaults
    log     global
    log-format {"type":"haproxy","timestamp":%Ts,"http_status":%ST,"http_request":"%r","remote_addr":"%ci","bytes_read":%B,"upstream_addr":"%si","backend_name":"%b","retries":%rc,"bytes_uploaded":%U,"upstream_response_time":"%Tr","upstream_connect_time":"%Tc","session_duration":"%Tt","termination_state":"%ts"}
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    option http-server-close
    maxconn 250
    timeout connect  5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000


# SSL/TLS Passthrough

frontend front_forward
    mode tcp
    bind haproxy:8080
    use_backend back_forward

backend back_forward
    server onpremsrv cloud:8881
    mode tcp
    timeout server 30s

frontend front_reverse
    mode tcp
    bind haproxy:8081
    use_backend back_reverse

backend back_reverse
    server onpremsrv cloud:8882
    mode tcp
    timeout server 30s

# SSL/TLS Passthrough

listen stats 
    bind haproxy:9000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats hide-version
    stats auth admin:admin
```